# find/search div id's and classes throughout the website using google chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm in the process of writing comments in a style sheet so I'm going through the style sheet line by line so for instance I have a style called #main , I'm searching for this in the tools  using the the search facility but this only searches in the current page not all pages , is there a way i can search the whole site for all instances..

Or is there some other tool i can use to do this ?

Comment: See my answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066809/find-where-element-is-selected-in-source

Answer (score 6):

**Find in all Sources**

CTRL-SHIFT-F on Windows and CMD-OPT-F on Mac. [link](https://plus.google.com/115133653231679625609/posts/e4W2kdrFJY9)

A few resources for leveling up your Chrome Dev Tools game:

- Addy Osmani on google plus.  [link](https://plus.google.com/+AddyOsmani/posts)
- The Breakpoint GoogleDevelopers Videos [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPXeWjWp-8Y)
- Chrome Canary - Get a jump on chromes new features [link](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html)