# Find where element is selected in source

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is the any way (Chrome Extension) search for all selections of an element in source JavaScript (or CSS for that matter) files? Basically, I want to see where the source code modifies the element. For example, when a button is clicked. Instead of searching for where the button clicked event is bound, Chrome Dev Tools would do it for me and show me. Is this possible within Chrome Dev Tools or an extension?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get chrome-devtools to actually search all JS sources?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944633/can-i-get-chrome-devtools-to-actually-search-all-js-sources)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is and it is awesome :)

CTRL-SHIFT-F on Windows and CMD-OPT-F on Mac. https://plus.google.com/115133653231679625609/posts/e4W2kdrFJY9

Enjoy!